# How can I group Matlab scripts on folders as executing from the main script at parent folder?

Tags: matlab

I have a dozen of scripts already and I want to group them under folders to deal with them with more ease. How could I do it? Does Matlab includes Packet hierarchy? If it does, I cannot find how to use :(.

Comment: Matlab support hierarchical folder structures for classes (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html). May be it can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Matlab uses [package directories](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) for that.

Group the files in a directory starting with a `'+'`:

```
+somePackage/func1.m
+somePackage/func2.m
```

then, in your main script,

```
import someDir.*

A = func1(arg1, arg2, ...);
B = func2(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

or

```
A = somePackage.func1(arg1, arg2, ...);
B = somePackage.func2(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

This is basically Matlab's implementation of the concept of namespaces.